# How to configure GatsbyJS firestore plugin re. timestampsInSnapshots change

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gatsby

I have installed and configured the gatsby-source-firestore plugin.
When I run 'gatsby develop', the app launches.
In the terminal however, the following warning appears:

```
The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change
AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.
To hide this warning and ensure your app does not break, you need to 
add the following code to your app before calling any other Cloud 
Firestore methods:

  const firestore = new Firestore();
  const settings = {/* your settings... */ timestampsInSnapshots: 
  true};
  firestore.settings(settings);

With this change, timestamps stored in Cloud Firestore will be read 
back as Firebase Timestamp objects instead of as system Date objects. 
So you will also need to update code expecting a Date to instead 
expect a Timestamp...
```

The question is: how do I implement this change requirement into my firestore gatsby plugin?

Answer (score 1):

This is handled at a plugin level.
This behavior is also mentioned on Github here: https://github.com/taessina/gatsby-source-firestore/issues/12

The Github repo has been updated to avoid the alert but the maintainer hasn't updated the plugin on npm.
I suggested a temporary solution until he does.
You can install the plugin from the master branch on Github with

```
yarn add taessina/gatsby-source-firestore#master
```

or

```
npm i taessina/gatsby-source-firestore#master
```

Make sure to handle timestamps properly. My gatsby config looks something like that:

```
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-firestore',
      options: {
        credential: firestoreCredential,
        types: [
          {
            type: 'FirestoreEvent',
            collection: 'events',
            map: ({
              timeStart,
            }) => ({
              timeStart: timeStart.toDate(),
            }),
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```